# Python - appending range cannot be split

Tags: python

When I try

```
anylist.append([var[x:y].split()])
```

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

But

```
anylist.append([var[x].split()])
```

works fine. 
So can someone tell me: How can I append a range of a variable to my list and still get the items to split?

Cheers

PS:
This is supposed to be incorporated in a loop

```
for j in range(0,z):
```

So, for every j, I want a different range of my variable to be an item and the item is supposed to be split.

**EDIT**
Ok, I try to be more clear on my problem, so it's better to understand:
I want to process a file of the following format

```
480
STEP: 1
Ele  x  y  z
Ele  x  y  z
...
480
STEP: 2
Ele  x  y  z
...
```

Now, every block starts with '480' and is 480 + 2 lines long (+2 because of the first two lines in the block).

What I try to achieve is get get every block 'STEP: x' into one item of my list, and the lines in this step should be splitted.
The list should in the end therefore be like

```
[
 [[  480],[STEP:1],[Ele, x, y, z],[Ele, x, y, z],...],
 [[  480],[STEP:2],[Ele, x, y, z],[Ele, x, y, z],...],
 [[  480],[STEP:3],...]]
]
```

so that later I can process something like

```
if 3 <= float(anylist[0][3][1] <= 5
... do something...
```

where I would like to check, if in the first block (step: 1) the x-value lies between 3 to 5.

Coming back to my problem, I wanted to do something like this:

```
trj_list = []
for i in range(0,nsteps):
  for j in range(0,nat):
    trj_list.append(lines[j*nat:j*nat+nat])
```

The file has a total length of nat*nsteps. The first loop goes over nsteps = 2001, the second loop goes over nat = 482.
For every j, the second loop should append all lines (from 0-482) to a list in a list and the items should be split. 
So the first loop should go over all 'STEP:x' and the second loop should go over all lines in a block (which is 482 lines).

But the problem arises in the last 'trj_list.append' command, because I cannot split, when I use a range in 'lines[x:y]'.

Comment: Can you show an example of the behavior you would like? I'm having a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: @Cyber: edited, I hope it's better to understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you are slicing you get back a list instead of individual objects. You can use a simple list comprehension to operate your split on every object/string in the list though:

```
anylist.append([e.split() for e in var[x:y]])
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I found also another approach:

```
for i in range(var):
  anylist.append([var[i].split()])
```

I think this should also not load memory as much